# Why do I get 'no permissions' when trying to add documents to my OpenSearch index via Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-opensearch

I have some data that I need to index in my new OpenSearch instance with fine grained access control enabled.

I've created a Lambda function running the below Python code and added the below policies to the Lambda execution role:

- `AmazonESFullAccess`
- `AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess`

My code looks like below:

```py
import boto3
import re
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from data_to_index import bulk_data_to_index

region = 'ap-south-1' # e.g. us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

host = 'my_domain' # the OpenSearch Service domain, e.g. https://search-mydomain.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com
index = 'my_index'
datatype = '_doc'
url = host + '/' + index + '/' + datatype

headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

# Lambda execution starts here
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for data in bulk_data_to_index:
        document = {
            "key1": data[1],
            "key2": data[2],
            "data": ', '.join(data)
        }
        r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)

        # Print response content and status code
        print("Response Content:", r.content)
        print("Status Code:", r.status_code)

        # Check if the request was successful
        if r.status_code == 201:
            print("Document added successfully to OpenSearch!")
        else:
            print("Failed to add document to OpenSearch. Status code:", r.status_code)
            print("Error Response:", r.text)
```

When running the Lambda, I'm getting the error:

```json
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "security_exception",
            "reason": "no permissions for [indices:data/write/index] and User [name=my_lambda_role, backend_roles=[my_lambda_role], requestedTenant=null]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "security_exception",
      "reason": "no permissions for [indices:data/write/index] and User [name=my_lambda_role, backend_roles=[my_lambda_role], requestedTenant=null]"
   },
   "status": 403
}
```

Why does `AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess` not give me all the access I need?

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess` not give me all the access I need?

`AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess` provides full access for configuring the OpenSearch service. It allows any resource to perform any [`es:*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonopensearchservice.html#amazonopensearchservice-actions-as-permissions) action on any resource e.g. `es:DescribeDomain` to get the details for an OpenSearch domain or `es:DeleteDomain` to delete an OpenSearch domain.

It specifies the permissions the IAM principal has *outside* of the OpenSearch domains.

It doesn't specify the permissions that the IAM principal e.g. your Lambda function execution role has *within* the OpenSearch domain itself.

You've granted your Lambda function full access to configure domains, list domains, delete domains, update domain config, upgrade domains etc. but no access *within* the domain itself to - for example - add a document to an index.

> How do I fix this issue?

You need to do [role mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-mapping) to grant your Lambda execution role permissions *within* the domain.

Map the Lambda role ARN as a backend role to a custom role you've created, or one of the [predefined OpenSearch roles](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/access-control/users-roles/#predefined-roles) that would grant you access to add documents to the index e.g. `all_access`.

---

Roles like `all_access` should really only be used for limited testing. You should segregate your Lambda's permissions & have a separate OpenSearch role.

Following the principal of least privilege, the error indicates that the minimum permission required is `indices:data/write/index`. You should create a role, granting this permission on the index you want to write to.

However, you're most likely also using [dynamic mapping](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/field-types/index/#dynamic-mapping), meaning your next error would be *no permissions for `indices:admin/mapping/put`*. You'd also need to add this permission to your role.

If you're looking to *just* add documents, the above will be enough (two permissions for a dynamically-mapped index, one permission for an explicitly-mapped index). Open you OpenSearch Dashboard and navigate to *Security* > *Roles* > *Create Role* to create the truly-minimal role.

However, most of the time, you want to also carry out other actions like deleting documents, updating them etc.

In that case, for convenience, OpenSearch has grouped the single permissions of `indices:data/write*` and `indices:admin/mapping/put` together in the [`write`](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/access-control/default-action-groups/#index-level) action group.

This essentially provides permission to:

- perform all write operations to documents i.e. index, update & delete documents
- perform bulk operations
- allow for the index mapping to be dynamically updated

If you're looking to do general 'write operations', assign the `write` action group to your new role, targeting your specific index.

---

Once you have a role ready, you can do the role mapping via the [OpenSearch API](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/access-control/api/#create-role-mapping), or via the console following the [docs](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/access-control/users-roles/#map-users-to-roles):

1. Copy your Lambda function execution role ARN
2. Open OpenSearch Dashboard
3. Choose *Security* > *Roles*, and then a suitable OpenSearch role
4. Choose the *Mapped users* tab and *Manage mapping*.
5. Under Backend roles, paste the copied ARN
6. Click the 'Map' button

Your Lambda function should now have permission to create OpenSearch indexes for your specific domain.